# How do I make a button moved through css pushable?

Tags: html, css, button

I have two buttons like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; bottom: +95;">
<button name="" value="">Bypass</button>
<button name="open" value="n">Bypass</button>
</div>
```

When I click them, nothing happens, they are not interactable.

When I find them through pressing tab, the buttons do appear as interactable objects and I am able to push them down through pressing enter.

If I remove the `<div style="position: relative; bottom: +95;">`, they get pushable again, but obviously they aren't where I want them to.

Comment: `When I click them, nothing happens` what do you want to happen?

Comment: @Ashikirsha I want them to be pushed down? If I wasn't clear, nothing at all happens, no animation or anything, it's just like clicking on the background.

Comment: show your css for pushable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try z-index like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; bottom: +95; z-index: 9999;">
<button name="" value="">Bypass</button>
<button name="open" value="n">Bypass</button>
</div>
```

Comment: upvoted, but I'd use smaller value e.g. `z-index: 1;`